# Trying to move pixels from an image

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to take a grayscale image of a coin and move the pixels around for a new image. It looks like my code is re-assigning pixels into the new image, but I cannot see anything at the end. This is my first time using PIL and stack overflow!

```
from PIL import Image as image
import scipy.misc

im = image.open('dilation.jpg')
imageW = im.size[0]
imageH = im.size[1]
new = image.new("1",(imageW, imageH))
pixels = new.load()
b = round(imageW / 2)
n = b + 1

for x in range(imageW):
    for y in range(imageH):
        xy = (x,y)
        rgb = im.getpixel(xy)
        for i in range(3, -3,-1):          
        #Set new xy coordinates
            new_x = round(n * math.sin(i) + (width / 2))
            new_y = round(n * math.cos(i) + (height / 2))
            if new_x <= imageW and new_y <= imageH:
                pixels[new_x, new_y] = rgb

new
```

I expected to get some kind of altered version of my greyscale coin, but everything in the new image is still black for some reason. I can't figure out how to upload an image of my coin specifically, but it was generated by running Canny edge detection on my original image, like these: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7eee051142768d5ed6cadb8fa44ae435.webp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your code is running.

Here is a snippet to help you

```
import math
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image


im = Image.open('bee_hive.jpeg')
im = np.array(im)

imageW = im.shape[0]
imageH = im.shape[1]
imageC = im.shape[2]

new = np.zeros(im.shape)

for x in range(imageW):
    for y in range(imageH):
        rgb = im[x,y,:]
        for i in range(3, -3,-1):
        #Set new xy coordinates
            new_x = round(n * math.sin(i) + (imageW / 2))
            new_y = round(n * math.cos(i) + (imageW / 2))
            if new_x <= imageW and new_y <= imageH:
                new[new_x, new_y, :] = rgb


new = Image.fromarray(new.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
new.show()
```

The basic idea is to use numpy to generate a tensor (3D matrix) of your image. Then modifying your pixels is simply a rearrangement of the elements of the tensor.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you! I think my formula for generating the new coordinates was off, and making throwing the pixel locations out of bounds. I'm trying to straighten the coin text by changing the pixels based on an equation, and I guess I'm implementing it wrong.